# Eclipse Terminal on Mac not showing what I type

Tags: eclipse, macos, terminal

I've installed TM Terminal from Eclipse Marketplace on my Mac Mohave. However, when I try to type anything, the terminal does not show what I type at all! But when I hit enter, the command works. However, it still bugs me that I can't see what I'm typing because I could have plenty of typos and whatnot and its such an impediment. Anyone knows what could be wrong and how to fix this? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Going to **Help** -> **Check for Updates** seemed to fix the issue for me.